# Connected subsets of metric (or T1) spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I have proved some statements about *connected subsets* of a metric space. They are really basic, but I want to make sure that they are true. Would someone please tell me whether these statements are true or not?

**Statement 1**

> Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space.
>   Let $C$ be a connected subset of $X$.
>   If $C$ is finite, then $|C|≦1$.

**Statement 2**

> Let $X$ be a metric space.
>   Let $C$ be an infinite connected subset of $X$.
>   Then, $\forall p\in C$, $p$ is a limit point of $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.

For the first, if you assume that it is not a singleton or the empty set, you can use the "Hausdorffness" to create for every $x$ of $C$ an open set that separates $x$ from the rest of $C$ because $C$ is finite. By this you create a finite separation of $C$, and this is a contradiction to its contentedness.

For the second, every point in a set $A$ is a limit point of $A$ always, since you can take the constant sequence. But I guess you meant that for every $x$ in $C$, $x$ is a limit point of $C-\{x\}$.  In that case you can assume that it is not so. Then there's a subset of $X$, $U$, an open neighborhood of $x$ so that does not intersect with $C-\{x\}$ and let's say that $V$ is the intersection of $U$ and $C$, it's open in $C$, and $C-\{x\}$ is also open in $C$ since $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$ (metric space), so $V$ and $C-\{x\}$ form a separation of $C$, hence $C$ is not connected.

Comment: Thank you. I have a topology exam soon, so it is a very good practice!